# How to convert timestamp into date and time in java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestamp in json that is from a Linux server. I would like to convert it into a simple date-time format using Java.

I need the date and time in the following format: dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss

here is my JSON data:

```
[
  { 
    "batch_date": 1419038000
  }, 
  {
    "batch_date": 1419037000
  }
]
```

Comment: How are you parsing the Json? Look at gson or jackson

Comment: @pavankumarparasa Please avoid posting extraneous info and data. Minimize your scenario to the minimum needed to demonstrate your issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The batch date

```
"batch_date": 1419038000,
```

looks like seconds from epoch,

so

```
new Date (batch_date * 1000);
```

then use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) should do the trick

```
SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

-- code --

```
    long batch_date = 1419038000; 
    Date dt = new Date (batch_date * 1000); 

    SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(sfd.format(dt));
```

-- output --

```
20-12-2014 10:13:20
```

Comment: You mean `HH`, not `hh`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat can we read the timestamp? without using these DateFormats. I mean just by looking at it, can we say which year or month or date it is resembling.

Comment: the timestamp is in seconds since 1970/01/01 so yeah, if you have the skill you can work it out, but why would you?

Answer (score 3):

## No Such Data Type

There is no such thing as "JSON timestamp". JSON has [very few defined data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example). No date-time types among them.

As the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30994540/642706) by Scary Wombat states, your number is apparently a count of whole seconds from the Unix epoch of 1970. The java.util.Date class tracks time as milliseconds since the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), rather than whole seconds. So you need to multiply by 1,000. You also need to deal with `long` integers (64-bit) rather than `int` (32-bit). Append an uppercase `L` to the numeric literals, and declare any variables as `long`.

The java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. They are now supplanted by the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later, and/or the 3rd-party [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

Various JSON-processing libraries support converters for creating java.time or Joda-Time objects. Or you can perform a conversion in your code, shown below.

Be aware that both java.time and Joda-Time supports assigning a time zone. Code below assigns UTC for demonstration purposes, but you can assign your desired/expected zone.

## Joda-Time

Here is some code in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.8.1 showing the use of your input number as either seconds or milliseconds.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = 1419038000L;
DateTime dateTimeSeconds = new DateTime( secondsSinceEpoch , DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTimeMillis = new DateTime( secondsSinceEpoch * 1000L , DateTimeZone.UTC );  // Note the crucial "L" appended to the numeric literal.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "dateTimeSeconds: " + dateTimeSeconds );
System.out.println( "dateTimeMillis: " + dateTimeMillis );
```

When run.

```
dateTimeSeconds: 1970-01-17T10:10:38.000Z
dateTimeMillis: 2014-12-20T01:13:20.000Z
```

## java.time

Similar code to above, but using java.time of Java 8.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1419038000L );
ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , ZoneOffset.UTC );
ZonedDateTime zdtMontréal = zdtUtc.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "zdtUtc: " + zdtUtc );
System.out.println( "zdtMontréal: " + zdtMontréal );
```

When run.

```
zdtUtc: 2014-12-20T01:13:20Z
zdtMontréal: 2014-12-19T20:13:20-05:00[America/Montreal]
```

Comment: I mean...I have a timestamp in json

Comment: Good info for the comment about Time Zone ! I was wondering why I obtain **01**:13:20.000Z and not **10**:13:20 (as Scary Wombat ) for the time part !

Answer (score -3):

when we want read/parse a string value as date, we should know the date format of that input string, otherwise we will get wrong date value.

batch_date:1419038000 
what is the date format of this value ?

If we want to get the date value in the required format as in your case 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss'. there are two possible ways.

1) request batch_date value should be in your required format. or

2) if batch_date value is another format, we should know the original format, and build a Date object with original format using SimpleDateFormat parse method and then convert it into required format using another SimpleDateFormat format method.