# How can I get my date time in correct format while getting from database in spring and hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I am using spring and hibernate to develop an application.I have used

```
@Entity
public class Category {  
@CreationTimestamp
private java.sql.Timestamp created;
//getter and setter
}
```

for automatically saving the created time.It saves the created time well in  database like:

```
 2017-03-29 12:19:16
```

but when I get the json object my date is changed to another format like

```
"created": 1490769256000
```

My method for getting a category is:

```
public Category findCategoryById(int id) throws SQLException {
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return ((Category)session.get(Category.class,id));
}
```

How can I get it in the same format like it is saved in the database.

Comment: `1490769256000` millseconds since 1970/01/01 Can create a `Date` Object, can use SimpleDateFormat to format

Comment: Cant I get date in simple date format while retrieving from database using above method?

Comment: Yes jdbc allows you to get a value as a Date, but where does the json come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a timestamp in JSON into normal date and time in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994522/how-to-convert-a-timestamp-in-json-into-normal-date-and-time-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long long_date = 1490769256000L;

        Date dt = new Date (long_date); 

        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(sf.format(dt));
    }

}
```

check main method, by this way you can

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new java.time classes of JDK8 to convert as below:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1490769256000L), ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of Java's @JsonFormat Annotation. 
In this case, it would look like

```
@CreationTimestamp
//Json Format for your date here
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
private java.sql.Timestamp created;
```