# How to convert number to hour and minute in android

Tags: android, json, date-format

In my application i should show hour and minute and i get this numbers from **server** with this sample : 
**Json** :

```
{
  data:{
    time:84561
  }
}
```

i should get this **number** from **time** and show it with this format

```
**hh : mm : ss**
```

I can get number of time, but i can't convert this to `**hh : mm : ss**` .

How can i it?

Comment: what this number represent? seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30994540/5513005) might help you.

Comment: @Abhishek, seconds. can you help me? please

Comment: Convert it to milliseconds and then use Date class to get what you want.

Comment: @Abhishek, can you help me and send to me code? please. send me code. i really need this

Comment: see `DateUtils#formatElapsedTime`

Comment: @Abhishek No, *not* `Date`. The troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` & `java.util.Calendar` are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8+. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
long timeSec= 84561;// Json output
int hours = (int) timeSec/ 3600;
int temp = (int) timeSec- hours * 3600;
int mins = temp / 60;
temp = temp - mins * 60;
int secs = temp;

String requiredFormat = hours+ ": "+mins+": "+secs;//hh:mm:ss formatted string
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 9 answer

```
    Duration time = Duration.ofSeconds(87561);
    String hms = String.format("%02d : %02d : %02d", 
            time.toHoursPart(), 
            time.toMinutesPart(), 
            time.toSecondsPart());
```

Unfortunately in Java 8 `Duration` does not lend itself well to formatting. The methods I use in the snippet are introduced in Java 9 and will calculate the values for hh, mm and ss. Then `String.format()` does the rest.

I know you cannot use this on Andriod (yet), but I wanted to have this answer stand here for others who can use Java 9, now or in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**Very simple**

If this is unix time then it will be converted into human readable time format with this snippet.

```
String relavtiveTimeString = String.valueOf(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(unixTime));
```

You can use `new Date(unix);` and with below function you can get formatted date. You can format in different style.

```
//This mehtod convert the date into standard date like : 2017-12-23
    public static String getformateDate(Date dateObject) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return dateFormat.format(dateObject);
    }
```

For more information check this link already answer :
[Convert unix time stamp to date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432735/convert-unix-time-stamp-to-date-in-java)

Referance:

1. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html

Answer (score 0):

Pass your Number or timestamp and convert to milliseconds for hour and minute.use the below code.

```
 public static String getCurrentTimeStamp(String mCurrentTime) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy  hh:mm a z");
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        format.setTimeZone(tz);
        //  System.out.println("TimeZone   "+tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)+" Timezon id :: " +tz.getID());
        SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy  hh:mm a z");
        Date dateTime = null;
        try {
            dateTime = dateParser.parse(format.format(Long.parseLong((mCurrentTime)) * 1000));
            Log.e("Starttime", "Starttime" + format.format(dateTime));
            return format.format(dateTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just change the simpledateformat to below code .SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:HH:mm:ss", Locale.UK);

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Logic Use it As per Requirement**

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String json = "{\n" +
            "  data:{\n" +
            "    time:84561\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";

    Date date = new Gson().fromJson(json, Date.class);

    long milli = date.getTime() * 1000;

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(new java.util.Date(milli)));

}

class Date implements Serializable{

    int time;


    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

**Output**

> 05:30:00
>
> If you want to download Gson jar download it from

[here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm)